# Hyperlink que ao ser clicado abra um determinado aplicativo e caso não esteja instalado, abra o link do mesmo na Google Play?

Tags: android, link, android-intent

O aplicativo no caso é o **Telegram** e o mesmo trabalha com um sistema simples de referência a usuários, canais, grupos.

Gostaria que ao clicar no **hyperlink** (textView clicável) que está com o link do usuário @Fulano, o mesmo abrisse o Telegram e já o direcionasse ao usuário em questão.

Caso o Telegram não estivesse instalado, o link correspondente do mesmo na Google Play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger&hl=pt fosse aberto, para o usuário poder instalá-lo.

Já vi esse tipo de coisa acontecer em outro aplicativos, até mesmo em comentários do Youtube e no próprio navegador do meu smatphone. Aparece a opção de "abrir com".

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Edit:**

Tentei assim, com o código sugerido pelo ramaral, dessa vez não teve erros de execução, porém com o aparelho que teste que possui o telegram, não abriu o mesmo, mas a **câmera**.

**Activity:**

```
package genesysgeneration.hl;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvLink03;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvLink03=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLink03);
        PackageLinkMovementMethod.makerHyperlink(tvLink03);
        tvLink03.setMovementMethod(new PackageLinkMovementMethod("org.telegram.messenger"));

    }

}
```

**Classe herdada (PackageLinkMovementMethod):**

```
package genesysgeneration.hl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.style.URLSpan;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PackageLinkMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod{

    private String packageName;

    public PackageLinkMovementMethod(String packageName){

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event){

        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            Context context = widget.getContext();
            Intent laucnkIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

            if (laucnkIntent==null){

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ packageName));
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }else {

                context.startActivity(laucnkIntent);

            }

            return true;

        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);

    }

    public static void makerHyperlink(TextView textView){

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        ssb.append(textView.getText());
        ssb.setSpan(new URLSpan("#"), 0, ssb.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No xml, declare o TextView da forma habitual:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Abrir Telegram"/>
```

Escreva uma classe herdada de LinkMovementMethod que implemente o comportamento desejado.

**LinkMovementMethod.java**

```
public class PackageLinkMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {

    private String packageName;

    public PackageLinkMovementMethod(String packageName){

        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            Context context = widget.getContext();
            Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager()
                                         .getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

            if (launchIntent == null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ packageName));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                context.startActivity(launchIntent);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
    }

    public static void makeHyperlink(TextView textView) {
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        ssb.append(textView.getText());
        ssb.setSpan(new URLSpan("#"), 0, ssb.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
}
```

No java use assim:

```
    link = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.link);
    PackageLinkMovementMethod.makeHyperlink(link);
    link.setMovementMethod(new PackageLinkMovementMethod("org.telegram.messenger"));
```

### ---------------------------------

Resposta inicial:

Depois de ter o intent para a aplicação faça assim:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager
                   .queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if(activities.size() > 0){
    startActivity(intent);
else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=org.telegram.messenger"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

`queryIntentActivities()` retorna a lista de aplicações que podem tratar o intent.
Se houver 1 ou mais, o intent é lançado com `startActivity(intent)`.
Se não, é criado um intent para a página do aplicativo *org.telegram.messenger* no *market*.

**Edit:**

Vi que está a obter o intent através de `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`, então deve fazer assim:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.telegram.messenger");

if (launchIntent == null){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=org.telegram.messenger"));
    startActivity(intent);

}else {

    startActivity(launchIntent);

}
```

Comment: necessitarei colocar android:linksClickable na textview?

Comment: Tem de implementar um onClickListener para o TextView.

Comment: dá para fazer isso usando o `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())`?

Comment: adicionei um **intent** que nomeei de launchIntent com o intent do Telegram, porém ao clicar no no textView dá erro e o app para. cometi algum erro, deveria ter postado o código antes

Comment: o código do launch intent não funfou, irei tentar com a classe herdada que você dissertou

Comment: Todos os exemplos foram testados e funcionaram. Quando não "funfa" você deve informar o erro que ocorre.

Comment: no da classe herdada única coisa que acusou foi no public static void makerHyperlink => "inner classes cannot have static declarations"

Comment: Escreva a classe num arquivo java à parte.

Comment: fui testar no meu aparelho (nele tenho o telegram instalado) e abriu a camera!?!?!!

Comment: Como pode abrir a camera se está assim: `.setMovementMethod(new PackageLinkMovementMethod("org.telegram.messenger"));`?

Comment: nn faço a mínima ideiai. se quiser posto o código.